# Number of nodes at distance exactly r from the root of a tree with branching factor.

Tags: graph-theory, trees, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm feeling really stupid but I can't understand why in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5169) (page 3, right column) the number of nodes that are r hops away from the root of a tree with a branching factor equals to: $$(b+1)b^{r-1}$$
and the number of nodes not more than r hops away is:
$$[(b+1)b^r-2]/(b-1)$$

[image]

I thought it should be b^r and (b^(r+1)-1)/(b-1) correspondingly.

Comment: As I see it, your objection is valid, so the author is wrong, However, order of magnitude is the same..

Answer (score 3):

Suppose a tree has constant [valence or degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) $b+1$ or [branching factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor) $b$, by definition. The root has $b+1$ nodes adjacent to it in one hop. Each of those have a further $b$ nodes two hops from the root (hence branching factor), but they also are adjacent to the previous node which is the root. In general, any non-root node will have $b$ nodes which have distance from the root one greater, and $1$ node which is distance one less going back in the direction of the root. In other words, the root is special since all of its adjacent nodes are the same distance $1$ from itself, the root, but for all other nodes, their $b+1$ adjacent nodes split into $b$ nodes further from the root, and $1$ node closer to the root.

The two formulas regarding number of nodes at $r$ hops and at most $r$ hops are correct. Note that any $b$-ary tree can be isometrically embedded in the hyperbolic plane where each edge is given by a hyperbolic line segment and all have the same length which depends on $b$. The $b+1$ edges at any node are equally spaced angularly around that node with angle between adjacent edges $2\pi/(b+1)$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why root node has $b+1$ nodes if branching factor is $b$?

Comment: Okay, I think the answer is that *by convention* when we say branching factor $b$ it means degree of nodes are $b+1$. To make it consistent across all nodes, we need to have $b+1$ children for the root.

Answer (score 0):

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I8NE.jpg)
look at the picture 1, I think the author of that paper means justly,the root produces b+1 nodes, and each leaf node produce b nodes.
I think the author is not rigorous enough. because in graph theory, the branching factor is the number of children at each node.I think $b^r$ and $(b^{(r+1)}-b)/(b-1)$ correspondingly is better.
Maybe author just want to highlight the sentence ----"both growing $b^r$ with r"